# value directive is not binding when use mask in Angular

Tags: html, angular, ngx-mask

`<input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="phoneVariable" mask="000-000-0000"/>`

`[value]` is not working when I use `mask` in the input tag in Angular.

for example:  If `phoneVariable = "876-222-2222"` then `input` tag should display the value of the `phoneVariable`. i.e. 876-222-2222

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been resolved by using

`[(ngModel)]="phoneVarible"` instead of `[value]="phoneVaribale"`